# How to fix exception Device xxx disconnected while writing characteristic with yyy in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, utf-8, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am creating a BLE app where I am successfully connecting to a BLE device. I am able to read the GATT characteristics as well. But when I try to do write operation I get exception

> Device xxx disconnected while writing characteristic with yyy

This is my code

```
private async Task<string> ProcessDeviceInformationService(IService deviceInfoService)
        {
            try
            {
               await adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(device);
                var sb = new StringBuilder("Getting information from Device Information service: \n");
                var characteristics = await deviceInfoService.GetCharacteristicsAsync();
                var characteristic = await deviceInfoService.GetCharacteristicAsync(Guid.Parse("00002b0f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));

                //{
                    try
                    {
                        
deviceInfoService.GetCharacteristicAsync(GattCharacteristicIdentifiers.DataExchange);
                        if (characteristic != null)
                        {
                        var sbnew = new StringBuilder("BLE Characteristics\n");
                        byte[] senddata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.IsNullOrEmpty(SendMessageLabel.Text) ? "0x21" : SendMessageLabel.Text);

 

                        await Task.Delay(300);
                        
                         
                        var newbytes = await characteristic.WriteAsync(senddata);
                   

                        byte[] characteristicsvalue = characteristic.Value;
                        var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(characteristicsvalue);



                        sbnew.AppendLine($"Characteristics found on this device: {string.Join(", ", str.ToString())}");
                        CharactericsLabel.Text = sbnew.ToString(); 

                        
                   
                    }

 
                }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return ex.Message;
                    }
          
                return CharactericsLabel.Text;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
             
                return ex.ToString();
            }
   
        }
```

After some search I found that I need to pass hexadecimal value.Even I tried sending hexadecimal value as you can see in code but it's not working. **For android its working fine but for iOS it is still showing this exception**.I'm using device Iphone 8 plus and OS version of Iphone is 13.5.1.The write operation works in **Light Blue** app which I downloaded from App store for iOS. My **write type** is set to **default** which is **write with response**. But it is giving exception in my xamarin app only for the iOS part. I'm using latest stable **version 2.1.1 of Plugin.BLE**. I have no clue how to fix this any suggestions?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224791/discussion-on-question-by-judson-abraham-how-to-fix-exception-device-xxx-disconn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this exception by getting write without response for characteristic from the peripheral side.

Comment: I'm having the same issue when i send lots of lines. How do you get write without response? Thanks!

Comment: I noticed above there's a Task.Delay(300); it seems excessive but i tried it and so far the test are looking good (i'm using it for a joystick controller). I don't understand how this is possible, how would music and other things stream to devices? Would love an explanation, if anyone comes across this?